# Custom options in WPF PrintDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I'm in the process of migrating portions of an application from Windows Forms to WPF.  The current portion I'm working on involves printing a graph that represents a portion of time on a timeline.  We previously used the Windows Forms PrintDialog which offered the ability to print the "Current Page" and have custom checkboxes for application-specific options.  I'd like the option to print the section of the timeline the user is currently viewing, or producing a whole stack of pages if they want to print the entire timeline.

Using the WPF PrintDialog I don't see any way to do the same thing right off the bat.  From what I can tell the Current Page option is present and greyed out, but not supported by the dialog (which seems REALLY stupid).  Am I stuck creating a custom print dialog or is there an easier way I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`UserPageRangeEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.userpagerangeenabled.aspx) property of `PrintDialog` but that only for setting the Current page, or other pages.

If you need further customization, I'm afraid that you will need to clone the PrintDialog.